# How in JPA I can make save but after another save is already done?

Tags: java, jpa, save

How can I make a `save B` for `entity B` but under the condition that another `save A` is done and data is saved on table `A` (`entity A` )

Is it possible to make a "check" that B is done before saving A ?

is it enoght to do :

```
    personService.save(currentPerson);
    studentService.save(currentPerson);
```

I first need to have a Person (with personID as primary key) before saving a student (as that contains PersonID as foreign key)

Comment: What do `personService` and `studentService` do, exactly? How are the entities defined? If there's an association between `Student` and `Person`, usually it will be enough to make sure that association is populated

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: @crizzis i'll update my post

Comment: @deadshot I am using postgres

Comment: any relation between `Student` and `Person` entities?

Comment: Please show your mapping wiht all the entity code